# setBezelStyle not working on SWT NSButton - java

Tags: java, objective-c, macos, cocoa, swt

I'm creating an SWT (ported Mac OSX version) application. I am trying to set a specific button to have the bezel style of "inline". Here is what I want my button to look like on mac.

[image: inline button] (screenshotted in storyboard view in xcode)

The code I am using to try to get this inline button:

```
// created button named "inlineButton" and applied layout to it.
// here is where I set the bezel style and text.
NSButton nsInlineButton = (NSButton) inlineButton.view;
nsSaveButton.setBezelStyle(15); // NSBezelStyleInline is enum 15 for cocoa
this.inlineButton.setText("Inline Button");
```

And the result:

[image: buggy not inline button] (screenshotted from my java program)

I have also tried to redraw and relayout the shell and a variety of other methods with no avail.
Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I just needed to add the SWT style of "FLAT"

```
this.inlineButton = new Button(this, SWT.FLAT);
NSButton inlineButton = (NSButton) inlineButton.view;
inlineButton.setBezelStyle(15);
```